# Flux across a cone

Tags: calculus

Compute the flux of $F=(x,y,z^4)$ across the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, z \in [0,1]$ in the downward direction. (Answer is $\pi/3$.)

For this question I tried to use the divergence theorem: $\int\int_SF = \int\int\int_V\nabla F$

I got $\nabla F = 2+4z^3$ and used cylindrical coordinates: $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_r^1(2+4z^3)rdzdrd\theta$ but the answer I got was $4\pi/3$. Is this correct or did I do something wrong?

Comment: To use Gauss theorem you *must* have a closed, bounded surface. You seem to have bounded your cone from above at the plane $\;z=1\;$...but now you must substract the flux through that plane...

Comment: Not sure how to do that can you show me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe first that by using Gauss Theorem you in fact calculated the flux *outward* the surface

$$\left\{\left(x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\right\}\cap\{\left(x,y,1\right)\}\subset\Bbb R^3$$

Without the "upper cap", we only have the (open) cone, and "outwards" thus clearly means downwards.

The intersection of plane $\;z=1\;$ with the cone $\;z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\;$ is just the surface (in fact, the "canonical" unit circle at height one)  $\;S:\;r(t)=(\cos t, \sin t, 1)\;,\;\;0\le t\le 2\pi\;$ , and since we wanted the flux *down* the cone to begin with, we must subtract now the flux **up** through the above surface , thus we get that the normal vector to that circle is clearly $\;\vec n=(0,0,1)\;$ , and thus (using cylindrical coodinates):

$$\vec F\cdot\vec n=z^4\implies \iint_S\vec F\cdot\vec n\;dS=\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi} z^4\,r\,d\theta\,dr\stackrel{z=1\;\text{here}}=\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi} r\,d\theta\,dr=\pi$$

and thus the final flux is (according to what you already got using Gauss Theorem)

$$\frac{4\pi}3-\pi=\frac\pi3$$

Comment: How did you get $\;\vec n=(0,0,1)\;$?

Comment: As you bounded up $\;z=1\;$, you get the plane $\;z=1\;$, which of course is parallel to the $\;xy\;$ plane, and thus a unit normal *up* to that plane is $\;(0,0,1)\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

Same solution as "1 Answer" except:

The first display with a union, not an intersection, and the restriction $x^2+y^2\le 1$ is specified. Also what is called surface $S$, the intersection of $z=1$ and the solid cone $z \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, is parameterized by

$$r(a,t)=\langle a \cos(t),a \sin(t),1\rangle, \; 0 \le a \le1,\; 0 \le t \le 1.$$

Comment: Please use LaTeX. Thank you!